# Replacing various variables in expression with values?

Tags: java

In String `s`, there are variables and arrays. For example, `s` could be `a - (b+A[B[2]])*d + 3`, and the values for those variables are stored in a separate file. This is a segment of my code in which I am trying to replace any variables in my current string `s` with their corresponding value from the other file.

I only want to replace the variables that are scalar variables, not arrays, and I have an ArrayList called `scalars` which has all scalar variables stored. So for the given example, with `a=1`, `b=2`, `d=3` I would want to make `s` into `1 - (2+A[B[2]])*3 + 3`. `scalars` also does not contain duplicate variables, so my code only works for single, non duplicate variables such as `a,b,c` and not for variables such as `varx`. How could I improve my code to work for every situation, or is there a better approach?

```
String s = expr; 

    if(scalars.size()>0){
        int j = 0; //make so duplicates can be used , so var can be used, so it doesn't detect arrays
        for(int k = 0; k<s.length(); k++){
            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(k))){
                s= s.substring(0,k) + this.scalars.get(j).value + s.substring(k+1,s.length());
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: full evaluate code (not yet complete). I am trying to convert it to a String without variables so I can eventually recursively call evalNoPB when I introduce parentheses/brackets

```
    public float evaluate() { 

    String s = expr; 

    if(scalars.size()>0){
        int j = 0; //make so duplicates can be used , so var can be used, so it doesn't detect arrays
        for(int k = 0; k<s.length(); k++){
            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(k))){
                s= s.substring(0,k) + this.scalars.get(j).value + s.substring(k+1,s.length());
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    float answer = 0;

    if(s==null || s.length() == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    //one single variable or just a number
    if(s.contains("+") == false && s.contains("-") == false && s.contains("*") == false && s.contains("/") == false && s.contains("[") == false &&s.contains("]") == false && s.contains("(") == false && s.contains(")") == false){ 
        if(scalars.size() == 0){
            answer = Float.parseFloat(s);
            return answer;
        }
        answer = this.scalars.get(0).value;
        System.out.println("one var/number loop");
        return answer;
    }


    //no parentheses/brackets
    if(s.contains("(") == false && s.contains(")") == false && s.contains("[") == false && s.contains("]") == false && (s.contains("+") == true || s.contains("-") == true || s.contains("*") == true || s.contains("/") == true)){
        System.out.println("no parens loop");
        answer = evalNoPB(s);
        return answer;
    }
    //make compiler happy 
    System.out.println("no loop");
    return 0;
    }

    //no parentheses/brackets
    private float evalNoPB(String s){ 

        float tempAns= 0;
        if(s.contains("*") == false && s.contains("/") == false && s.contains("+") == false && s.contains("-") == false){
            return Float.parseFloat(s);
        }

    if(s.length()-1>0){
        int i;
        boolean foundPlusMinus = false;
        for(i=s.length()-1; i>0; i--){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-'){
                System.out.println(i);
                foundPlusMinus = true;
                break; // keep value of i for substrings 
            }
            foundPlusMinus = false;
        } 

        if (foundPlusMinus == false) { // for loop went through and did not find + or -
            for(i=s.length()-1; i>0; i--){
                if(s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/'){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break; // keep value of i for substrings
        }
    }
    }

    String sub1 = s.substring(0,i);
    System.out.println(sub1);
    String sub2 = s.substring(i+1, s.length());
    System.out.println(sub2);

    if(s.charAt(i) == '+'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) + evalNoPB(sub2);
    } else if(s.charAt(i) == '-'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) - evalNoPB(sub2);
    }else if(s.charAt(i) == '*'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) * evalNoPB(sub2);
    }else if (s.charAt(i) == '/'){
        float divisorCheck = evalNoPB(sub2);
        if(divisorCheck!= 0){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) / evalNoPB(sub2);
        }else { // cannot divide by 0 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot divide by 0");
        }
}
}
    return tempAns;

}
```

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If you want to replace the value of a string,do not use the String class because String is imutable,instead use StringBuffer or StringBuilder.One it is faster than the other and the other one is thread safety. Google StringBuffer tutorial ;)

Comment: I cannot use StringBuilder because I cannot import anything to the assignment, unfortunately. Would the replace()method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a compiler, a rather complicated program which parses input in a certain programming language and transforms it into another programming language.

In this case the input language would be expressions with numbers, scalar variables, array variables, sums, multiplications and parenthesis.
The output language would be expressions with numbers, array variables, sums, multiplications and parenthesis (note it does not contain scalar variables).

There is a lot of literature about compilers. It is a subject which spans several courses in computer science university degrees.
You can get away with simple substitutions if you define a very restricted language, as in OP. But once you start dealing with more general languages, like variables of length longer than 1, you start needing the whole architecture to build a compiler.

A compiler has several parts :

1. A lexical parser. This breaks the input in TOKENS. Each token being an identifier, an operator and similar things. The lexical analyzer also removes blanks from the input.
2. A syntactical parser. A set of rules that define the language in terms of TOKENS. Often done with [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).
3. A semantical translator. This can take a structure built in the syntactical parser or can be interwoven in the syntactical parser. It translates the input language into the output language.
4. And some other optional parts, line an optimizer, which are beyond the scope of this question.

**Lexical parser**

The lexical parser is to break the input into tokens.
In example, consider the input "3+a".
The expected tokens are : NUMBER PLUS IDENTIFIER

I'll define the tokens in terms of regular expressions :

- PLUS : [+]
- MINUS : -
- MULTIPLY : [*]
- DIVIDE : /
- NUMBER : [0-9]+
- IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z]+
- OPEN_PARENTHESIS : [(]
- CLOSE_PARENTHESIS : [)]
- OPEN_BRACKET : \[
- CLOSE_BRACKET : \]
- EOL : no regular expression for End Of Line. The lexical parser will return this token when the input is exhausted.

Here is the code for the lexical parser.
First a Token class which holds a token, with its type and the substring of the input from which the token was generated.

```
public class Token
{
    public static enum TokenType
    {
        PLUS,
        MINUS,
        MULTIPLY,
        DIVIDE,
        NUMBER,
        IDENTIFIER,
        OPEN_PARENTHESIS,
        CLOSE_PARENTHESIS,
        OPEN_BRACKET,
        CLOSE_BRACKET,
        EOL // End of line
    }

    public Token( TokenType type, String value)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private TokenType type;
    public String value;

    public TokenType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Next the lexical analyzer proper.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import expressionparser.Token.TokenType;

class Tokenizer
{
    private final String input;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private Token lastToken;

    public Tokenizer( String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
        Pattern pattern =
                Pattern.compile( "[+]|-|[*]|/|[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[(]|[)]|\\[|\\]|[ ]");
        matcher = pattern.matcher( input );
        lastToken = null;
    }

    public Token readAndComsumeToken( TokenType type ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        Token result = readToken();
        if ( result.getType()!=type )
            throw new ExpressionException("Erroneous exception" );
        lastToken = null;
        return result;
    }

    public Token readToken() throws ExpressionException
    {
        if (lastToken!=null)
            return lastToken;

        String value;
        // Read till a non blank is received
        do
        {
            if ( matcher==null )
            {
                lastToken = new Token(TokenType.EOL, "");
                return lastToken;
            }
            if ( !matcher.find() )
              throw new ExpressionException("Erroneous exception" );
            value = matcher.group();
            if ( matcher.end() >= input.length() )
            {
                // End of String
                matcher = null;
            }
            if ( value.length()==0 )
              throw new ExpressionException("Erroneous exception" );
        } while ( value.equals( " " ) ||
                 value.equals("\t") || value.equals("\n") ||
                 value.equals("\f") || value.equals("\r") );
        // Identify read token
        TokenType type;
        if ( value.equals("+") )
            type = TokenType.PLUS;
        else if ( value.equals("-") )
            type = TokenType.MINUS;
        else if ( value.equals("*") )
            type = TokenType.MULTIPLY;
        else if ( value.equals("/") )
            type = TokenType.DIVIDE;
        else if ( value.equals("(") )
            type = TokenType.OPEN_PARENTHESIS;
        else if ( value.equals(")") )
            type = TokenType.CLOSE_PARENTHESIS;
        else if ( value.equals("[") )
            type = TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET;
        else if ( value.equals("]") )
            type = TokenType.CLOSE_BRACKET;
        else
        {
            char firstChar = value.charAt(0);
            if ( firstChar>='0' && firstChar<='9' )
                type = TokenType.NUMBER;
            else
                type = TokenType.IDENTIFIER;
        }
        lastToken = new Token( type, value );
        return lastToken;
    }

    public void consumeToken() throws IllegalStateException
    {
        if ( lastToken==null )
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        lastToken = null;
    }
}
```

Tokenizer is based on Pattern a standard java class which can break up strings as dictated by regular expressions.
The constructor creates a Pattern matcher for the input expression.
The Pattern has an extra regular expression `[ ]` not included in the previous list of tokens. This reads white spaces but they are not turned into tokens by `Tokenizer`, they are ignored.

`readToken` gets the next token from the matcher ignoring white spaces. It saves it in `lastToken` because the syntactical parser may need to call several times `readToken` for the same token and `readToken` needs to always return the same token until it is consumed. If there was already a not consumed token from a previous call it is returned without getting a new one.

`consumeToken` consumes the last read token by setting `lastToken` to `null`. It is an error to call it without having called before `readToken`.

`readAndComsumeToken` is a convenience method. In some cases the syntactical parser will know what the next token is before reading it. In that case it needs to read it, verify that it is the expected one and consume it. `readAndConsumeToken` does it in a single call.

**Syntactical parser.**

For the syntactic parser first we create a context-free grammar which defines the input language.
I will use [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for it.

```
<wholeExpression>    ::= <expression> EOL
<expression>         ::= <summand> <tailSum>
<summand>            ::= <factor> <tailMultiplication>
<factor>             ::= OPEN_PARENTHESIS <expression> CLOSE PARENTHESIS |
                         NUMBER |
                         IDENTIFIER <tailArray>
<tailSum>            ::= PLUS <summand> <tailSum> |
                         MINUS <summand> <tailSum> |
                         ""
<tailMultiplication> ::= MULTIPLY <factor> <tailMultiplication> |
                         DIVIDE <factor> <tailMultiplication> |
                         ""
<tailArray>          ::= OPEN_BRACKET <expression> CLOSE_BRACKET <tailArray> |
                         ""
```

There are several ways to implement such grammar. And there are even tools to do it automatically.
I will implement it using a Java method for each non-terminal of the grammar. It is presented in the semantical translator since that is interwoven with the parser.

**Semantical translator.**

`ExpressionParser` is the syntactical parser and the semantical translator combined. It uses `Tokenizer` for doing the lexical analysis.

```
import expressionparser.Token.TokenType;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpressionParser
{
    private Tokenizer lex;
    private List<Scalar> scalars;

    public String compile( String expression, List<Scalar> scalars ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        lex = new Tokenizer(expression);
        this.scalars = scalars;
        return evalWholeExpression();
    }

    private String evalWholeExpression( ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        String result = evalExpression();
        lex.readAndComsumeToken(Token.TokenType.EOL);
        return result;
    }

    private String evalExpression() throws ExpressionException
    {
        String left = evalSummand();
        return evalTailSum( left );
    }

    private String evalSummand( ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        String left = evalFactor();
        return evalTailMultiplication( left );
    }

    private String evalFactor() throws ExpressionException
    {
        Token token = lex.readToken();
        if ( token.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_PARENTHESIS )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String result = evalExpression();
            lex.readAndComsumeToken(TokenType.CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
            return "(" + result + ")";
        }
        else if ( token.getType() == TokenType.NUMBER )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            return token.toString();
        }
        else if ( token.getType()==TokenType.IDENTIFIER )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String tailArray = evalTailArray();
            if ( "".equals(tailArray) )
            {
                String scalarValue = evaluateScalar( token.toString() );
                return scalarValue;
            }
            else
            {
                verifyIsNotScalar( token.toString() );
                return token + tailArray;
            }
        }
        else
            throw new ExpressionException( "Incorrect expression" );
    }

    private String evalTailSum( String left ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        Token token = lex.readToken();
        if ( token.getType()==TokenType.PLUS )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String right = evalSummand();
            return evalTailSum( left + "+" + right );
        }
        else if ( token.getType()==TokenType.MINUS )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String right = evalSummand();
            return evalTailSum( left + "-" + right );
        }
        else
            return left;
    }

    private String evalTailMultiplication( String left ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        Token token = lex.readToken();
        if ( token.getType()==TokenType.MULTIPLY )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String right = evalFactor();
            return evalTailSum( left + "*" + right );
        }
        else if ( token.getType()==TokenType.DIVIDE )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String right = evalFactor();
            return evalTailSum( left + "/" + right );
        }
        else
            return left;
    }

    private String evalTailArray() throws ExpressionException
    {
        Token token = lex.readToken();
        if ( token.getType() == TokenType.OPEN_BRACKET )
        {
            lex.consumeToken();
            String result = evalExpression();
            lex.readAndComsumeToken(TokenType.CLOSE_BRACKET);
            return "[" + result + "]" + evalTailArray();
        }
        else
            return "";
    }

    private String evaluateScalar( String text ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        assert text!=null;
        for ( Scalar s : scalars )
        {
            if ( text.equals( s.identifier ) )
                return "" + s.value;
        }
        throw new ExpressionException( "Incorrect expression" );
    }

    private void verifyIsNotScalar( String text ) throws ExpressionException
    {
        assert text!=null;
        for ( Scalar s : scalars )
        {
            if ( text.equals( s.identifier ) )
                throw new ExpressionException( "Incorrect expression" );
        }
    }

}
```

`compile` creates a `Tokenizer` lexical analyzer for the input and saves the list of Scalars. It then calls `evalWholeExpression`, which returns the translation of the input, and returns such translation.
If the input is not valid an ExpressionException is thrown. Such exception would contain the error message. Which I have not made an effort to make useful. Dealing with error messages is a whole subject itself.
There is a method eval<non-terminal> for each non-terminal of our context-free grammar.
The grammar has been composed in such a way that examining the 1st token is enough to determine which branch to take for non-terminals with several options. This makes easy creating the eval methods.

In example, consider `evalTailSum`. This method implements this rule :

```
<tailSum>            ::= PLUS <summand> <tailSum> |
                         MINUS <summand> <tailSum> |
                         ""
```

Which is used by itself and by this rule :

```
<expression>         ::= <summand> <tailSum>
```

`evalExpression` calls `evalSummand` and gets the translation of the left side of a possible summation ( or substraction ). Then it calls `evalTailSum` passing it this translation; finally returning the result of it.

<tailSum> has three branches.

1. One for sumation which always starts with SUM token.
2. One for substraction which always starts with MINUS token.
3. Otherwise the empty string. Which also happens for a fixed set of possible tokens. But there is no need to deal with this here.

So `evalTailSum` gets the next token with `lex.readToken()`. And then...

1. If it is PLUS it consumes it. Calls `evalSummand` storing its result as `right`. And calls 'evalTailSum' passing to it as left value `left + "+" + right`. Notice how the sequence of token consumption and calls matches the terminals and non-terminals in the right side of the <tailSum> rule.
2. If it is MINUS it follows a similar procedure to the PLUS case.
3. Otherwise the empty string branch is taken and the `left` translation received is returned as the result.

The same schema is followed to create a method for each non-terminal in the context-free grammar.

All those methods are not actually translating much at all. They produce as output the same as they received from input.
But that is not the case for one important method : `evalFactor`
When it deals with the IDENTIFIER branch we are in the place where we need to translate variables into values as specified by a list of Scalars.

Implementing Scalar is simple :

```
public class Scalar
{
    public Scalar( String identifier, int value )
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public final String identifier;
    public final int value;
}
```

In the IDENTIFIER branch `evalFactor` consumes the identifier and calls `evalTailArray` as per the <factor> rule in the context-free grammar.
`evalTailArray` returns an empty string if there are no array subscrits, so IDENTIFIER must be a scalar variable. In this case it calls `evaluateScalar` which searchs for that scalar in the list of scalars and returns its value so that it is translated, or if not found it will throw an ExpressionException.
If the result of `evalTailArray` is not empty it must be an array. We do no translation here as per OP. But we do verify that there is no scalar with that name by calling `verifyIsNotScalar`. If such verification fails this would be a semantic error (and so is if we have a non listed non-array variable), similar to the "undefined variable" or "incompatible type" errors you may get from a C++ or Java compiler. While all other errors thrown by our compiler would be syntactic errors similar to "syntax error : ; expected" or lexical errors like "illegal character @".

**Using it**

This small program uses the previous parser and tests it with several expressions. The last one being an incorrect expression.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            final List<Scalar> scalars = new ArrayList<>();
            scalars.add( new Scalar( "a", 1 ) );
            scalars.add( new Scalar( "b", 2 ) );
            scalars.add( new Scalar( "d", 3 ) );
            scalars.add( new Scalar( "varx", 5  ) );

            ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser();

            System.out.println( parser.compile("a - (b+A[B[2]])*d + 3", scalars));
            System.out.println( parser.compile("5*(2+varx)+a", scalars));
            System.out.println( parser.compile("B[a*384+(5+(5*(varx+3)))]+varx", scalars));
            System.out.println( parser.compile("34+", scalars ) );
        }
        catch (ExpressionException ex)
        {
            System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Output is as expected :

```
1-(2+A[B[2]])*3+3
5*(2+5)+1
B[1*384+(5+(5*(5+3)))]+5
Incorrect expression
```